# MediaWiki user preferences - hide some fields?

Tags: mediawiki

We've integrated MediaWiki with our website and wish to block/hide the editing of some fields in the Special:Preferences page so these cannot be changed by users.

Specifically: we don't want users to be able to change their email and language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a hook and unset the relevant fields. See: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/GetPreferences

```
public static function onGetPreferences(User $user, array &$preferences ) {
    unset($preferences['language']);
}

$wgHooks['GetPreferences'][] = 'MyHooks::onGetPreferences';
```

Comment: Is this part of the question? Or are you answering your own question? Gonna remove this until this is clear.